US Retailer Reprints Hard Copy Of My Receipt Without Consent
I feel like I am being profiled at a neighborhood store that is a part of a national retail chain. Example similar to the likings of TJ Maxx, Marshalls Ross Dress For Less.
I shop there quite frequently and I do return what I don't need. But after doing the math I spend around 25k (maybe a part timers salary) annually across these chains. An addict maybe? But nonetheless a loyal customer who should get respect when spending dollars there...
Today a manager took a copy of my receipt without my consent. No problem, if it is a part of company protocol and helps you out great, however it seemed that I was the only one in line that they did this with.
I've had a couple incidences with them where they contradict their processes and I'm able to prove it with receipts and logged transactions. Anyhow, can a retail store print a copy of your receipt without asking you and why?
I spent over $100 today and around $500 with this retail chain in less than a week. After 30 plus years of shopping there since I was a child, I'm finally stepping up, tired of the aggressive tactics pressed upon myself and other mutual frequent loyal shoppers,
while we all watch other people walk out with backpack loads of stolen items who get untouched as they escape the store.
Yet those of us compliant customers who patiently wait our turn in line, pay respectfully, or if we have returns with receipts & respective tags attached, why are we the ones getting penalized for doing the right thing?
I totally understand the stance of store associates and realize the climate within the retail industry has changed dramatically over the years. But why target those in compliance , bc you can???
Maybe I just need to reroute my dollars somewhere else and care less about finding treasures at an amazing discount. I get it, maybe my dollars don't matter , just a small fraction of the piece of the pie.
Anyhow, it could be that after all these years of enduring and tolerating treatment because to pay the price of a good deal one gets what they pay for, just done and ready to call it a day to contributing to such an ecosystem that doesn't appreciate loyalty.
Thanks in advance for any insight.

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really a question.

You mean their receipt?
Because it’s their record of the sale they made.
Of course they can.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
